# SSH to router shows man in the middle attack, am I being attacked?

Tags: router, ssh, dns, subdomain, man-in-the-middle

This starts to happen after I changed certain things.  I am in the progress learning how to setup my own server at home, have that server be accessible in public outside my LAN.

In the mist of trying things, yesterday I update my website subdomain to point to my router's public IP .   I also have port forwarding set for "from port 80" to "to port 80" and "from port 443" to "to port 443" forwarded to an internal IP: `192.168.1.153`.

Within home WiFi when I visit that domain which point to public WAN IP, I landed on the router's default info page (`192.168.1.1`).  From outside home LAN (cell phone network), same domain can't be loaded.  A DNS checker website shows the domain has been propagated with my WAN IP.

There is more things I changed but all on the linux machine side,  I believe above things are the only things I changed on the router side.

Now when I try to `ssh root@192.168.1.1`, it gives me warning:

```
➜  ~ ssh root@192.168.1.1
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:/TGdh+PsxBdanc2h3TlJOIwsRg4SahuOMemOSOPIyn4.
Please contact your system administrator.
```

Solution is to add a correct host key to avoid this warning.

Question is: am I really being attacked? Or this is because I shouldn't pointed the subdomain to my public IP address (DNS A record).  I changed the DNS A record back to original value.  I did DNS update via WIX.com admin page.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding what you are trying to achieve with the described settings, but from what you describe here I think that A)You aren't being attacked B) You have very poor security settings C) Your troubles are derived from poor settings.

Comment: I am trying to setup a file sharing server (NextCloud) on my NAS server, and having it accessible to outside world.  To do that. 1). I need to have a public domain name available. 2) DNS records pointing that domain name to your public IP address. 3) On router, ports 80 and 443 need to be forwarded to the internal IP of my nas server. 4) a TLS certificate (self-signed or trusted), and configure your installation to use it.  Above settings complete 1,2,3 and I am seeing Man in the middle attack now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is because the host key fingerprint has changed on the target host.  This happens if you regenerate the target host's ssh keys.  This typically happens if you rebuilt your target OS (i.e. reinstalled the OS on it).  The new fingerprint is different than what is stored in your known_hosts file.

The solution is to do ssh-keygen -R _target_host_ to remove the old fingerprint info.  When you next run ssh, it will ask you to add in the new fingerprint into your known_hosts file.   Say yes and you're good to go.

Of course, only do the above if you know you've rebuilt your target host or something like that.  If you have not rebuilt the target host, then you may be seeing a man in the middle attack.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Understand fingerprint changed in known_hosts file, but unsure how that's changed...  Oh thank you, I remember now.  I did re-flash my router to a different version sometime ago. I forget about that.  You totally reminded me.  Mystery resolved.